# Cannot find type 'IAxisValueFormatter' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am trying to use the library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts but recently it is giving me a problem in this part:

```
final class CustomDateFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override init() {
super.init()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-yy"
}

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: Int(value), to: Date())
return dateFormatter.string(from: newDate ?? Date()).lowercased()
}

}
```

The error is:

```
Cannot find type 'IAxisValueFormatter' in scope
```

Comment: Charts is a nice framework, but Apple has a native framework as of iOS 16. If your chart is not too advanced and you can get away with supporting only iOS 16, I think you'll probably find iOS's Charts framework easier to work with and no third party imports.

Comment: To resolve the immediate issue, make sure you've got `import <Whatever the name of the framework is>` in your file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like `IAxisValueFormatter` was renamed to `AxisValueFormatter`.
More info can be found https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4775